# On PHP script end send message to jquery, print to page with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page with buttons, that when pressed send an ajax request through jquery to a PHP script. This script runs with these variables. When this PHP script is finished I would like to send a message back to the jquery function, which then prints out this message. Currently I have:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    nombre = $('input').val();
    buttonz = $(this);
    buttonz.text('Loading...');
    request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'administrator.php',
        data: {
            'method': buttonz.attr('id'),
            'results': nombre
        },
    });
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        buttonz.text('Finished');
    });
});
```

Instead of 'finished' I would like to echo a varaible from my php script.

Comment: Have you tried `buttonz.text(response);`?

Comment: can u show your php script ??

Comment: I would `echo` from the PHP script and do what @DKasipovic said

Comment: is buttons is a button?

Comment: Do `<?php echo "Some text"; ?>` in php and then in javascript change `buttonz.text('Finished');` to `buttonz.text(response);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First need to check console error if you have any error then try to alert response in success section try

```
$('button').click(function () {
    nombre = $('input').val();
    buttonz = $(this);
    buttonz.text('Loading...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'administrator.php',
        data: {
            'method': buttonz.attr('id'),
            'results': nombre
        },
        success: function (data) {
                buttonz.text(data);
                // or use buttonz.val(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `ECHO` from jQuery as this is PHP and the server-side script has already been run. What you need to do is enter the text or html into an existing element.

For example..

On your page (before ajax is done) create a blank DIV with space to put the response ie...

`<div id="MyAnswerHere"></div>`

Then in your ajax call in the `success` area add the code to insert the answer. For example

`$("#MyAnswerHere").html(response);`

Or if just text you could use...

`$("#MyAnswerHere").text(response);`

So in your code..

```
$('button').click(function () {
    nombre = $('input').val();
    buttonz = $(this);
    buttonz.text('Loading...');
    request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'administrator.php',
        data: {
            'method': buttonz.attr('id'),
            'results': nombre
        },
    });
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#MyAnswerHere").text(response);
        buttonz.text('Finished');
    });
});
```

And add the div to enter the message do with the ID that we are selecting in the DOM before hand.

```
`<div id="MyAnswerHere"></div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

simply put the response from ajax in your button,

```
buttonz.text(response);
```

cheers

Comment: I added the following to my PHP script `echo "fin";` and then changed to `.text(response);`, however this does not produce anything

Comment: if you would alert the response can you paste what is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, which will change your button text when the ajax has succeeded:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    nombre = $('input').val();
    buttonz = $(this);
    buttonz.text('Loading...');
    request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'administrator.php',
        data: {
            'method': buttonz.attr('id'),
            'results': nombre
        },
        success: function (data) {
          buttonz.text(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `buttonz.text('Finished');` to:

```
buttonz.text('<?php echo json_encode(utf8_encode($your_Value))?>');
```

Answer (score -3):

So why not just to echo the variable with php??

Change buttonz.text('Finished'); to:

```
buttonz.text('<?php echo $your_variable;?>');
```

The value of the variable will be parsed by the PHP engine, it will appear in your HTML page as requested

Comment: No knowledge, the server side script at this stage has already run, this wouldn't run the code and just wouldn't work. OP ignore this answer.

Comment: Oh just saw that you refer to a variable which was sed already, so my answer is wrong :(